# Ruby regex puncuation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am having trouble writing this so that it will take a sentence as an argument and perform the translation on each word without affecting the punctuation.

I'd also like to continue using the partition method.

It would be nice if I could have it keep a quote together as well, such as:

"I said this", I said.

would be:

"I aidsay histay", I said.

```
def convert_sentence_pig_latin(sentence)
  p split_sentence = sentence.split(/\W/)
  pig_latin_sentence = []
  split_sentence.each do |word|
    if word.match(/^[^aeiou]+/x)
      pig_latin_sentence << word.partition(/^[^aeiou]+/x)[2] +  word.partition(/^[^aeiou]+/x)[1] + "ay"
    else
      pig_latin_sentence << word
    end
  end
  rejoined_pig_sentence = pig_latin_sentence.join(" ").downcase + "."
  p rejoined_pig_sentence.capitalize
end

convert_sentence_pig_latin("Mary had a little lamb.")
```

Comment: What are the rules of your pig latin? You should consider splitting with space. Then extract punctuation around words before adding them back after translation for each word.

Comment: Please note that the tags "pig" and "piglatin" have specific meanings on this site and this question does not relate to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that `[^aeiou]` matches **every** character outside that range, including spaces, commas, quotation marks, etc.

If I were you, I'd use a positive match for consonants, ie. `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]`  I would also put that regex in a variable, so you're not having to repeat it three times.

Also, in case you're interested, there's a way to make your `convert_sentence_pig_latin` method a single gsub and it will do the whole sentence in one pass.

### Update

...because you asked...

```
sentence.gsub( /\b([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])(\w+)/i ) { "#{$2}#{$1}ay" }
```

Comment: I see what you are saying. Would you mind me asking more about the gsub line?  I have only used gsub a handful of times. I am going to go ahead and try the consonant thing.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I've added the positive consonant matching, but it is still not ignoring the punctuation.  @smathy

Comment: Yeah, I think because of the `\W` split, you'd have to amend that too.  But see my `gsub`-based solution, it's much simpler.

Comment: Wow!  That makes so much more sense.  I amended the \W, but it still place the comma in the middle of the final word.  What does the m variable represent in the block?  Why is not being called?

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to put that there.See [the block form of `gsub` here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub), basically the matched text is passed in

Comment: I would definitely recommend checking out [regexr](http://www.regexr.com/). It's helped me a lot over the years.

Comment: Thank you.  I've been using rubular, but I can see that there may be more functionality with the regexr.  Again, thank you so much.  I knew there was a better way to do this and you really made me understand it well.

Answer (score 0):

```
# iterate over and replace regexp matches using gsub
def convert_sentence_pig_latin2(sentence)
  r = /^[^aeiou]+/i
  sentence.gsub(/"([^"]*)"/m) {|x| x.gsub(/\w+/) {|y| y =~ r ? "#{y.partition(r)[2]}#{y.partition(r)[1]}ay" : y}}
end
puts convert_sentence_pig_latin2('"I said this", I said.')

# define instance method: String#to_pl
class String
  R = Regexp.new '^[^aeiou]+', true # => /^[^aeiou]+/i
  def to_pl
    self.gsub(/"([^"]*)"/m) {|x| x.gsub(/\w+/) {|y| y =~ R ? "#{y.partition(R)[2]}#{y.partition(R)[1]}ay" : y}}
  end
end
puts '"I said this", I said.'.to_pl
```

sources:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub